# Predecessor-subgraph property

Tags: graphs, algorithm-analysis

In the proof of the predecessor subgraph property (page 14 of the following notes)
http://www.cs.sfu.ca/CourseCentral/307/binay/shortestpath.pdf
$d[v_i] \geq d[v_{i-1}]+w(v_{i-1},v_{i})$ is assumed true. Why is this? Shouldn't it be the other inequality:  $d[v_i] \leq d[v_{i-1}]+w(v_{i-1},v_{i})$ by triangle inequality?

Comment: Please quote the property and relevant conditions made on the graphs. The link may rot.

Answer (score 0):

I think the LHS is assumed by argument to be: $d[v_{i}]= \Sigma_{j=1}^{j=i} w(v_{j-1},v_{j})$. Since $d[v_{i-1}]= \delta(s,v_{i-1})$ = $min$$\{w(p) : s \rightsquigarrow^p v_{i-1}\} $  on the RHS, where $w(p)= \Sigma_{j=1}^{j=k}w(x_{j-1},x_{j})$ for any path $p: x_{0}=s, ... ,x_{k}=v_{i-1}$, we have the inequality $d[v_{i}]\geq d[v_{i-1}]+w(v_{i-1},v_{i})$.